# Windows Phone 7 Operation not permitted on IsolatedStorageFileStream

Tags: xml, windows-phone-7, isolatedstorage

I'm working on a app that has a directory, and it pulls it in via XML from the web, writing it to a local XML file, and then reading it from there to display the contacts. I'm having issues with my IsolatedStorageFileStream not working, because the operation is not permitted. Here is my code:

```
IsolatedStorageFile isoStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
        IsolatedStorageFileStream file = isoStorage.OpenFile("Components/contacts.xml", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Read);
        var reader = new StreamReader(file);
        XElement appDataXml = XElement.Load(reader);
        lstContacts.ItemsSource = from contact in appDataXml.Descendants("contact")
                                  select new ContactItem
                                  {
                                      ImageSource = contact.Element("Image").Value,
                                      FName = contact.Element("FName").Value,
                                      LName = contact.Element("LName").Value,
                                      Extension = contact.Element("Extension").Value,
                                      Email = contact.Element("Email").Value,
                                      Cell = contact.Element("Cell").Value,
                                      Title = contact.Element("TitleName").Value,
                                      Dept = contact.Element("deptName").Value,
                                      Office = contact.Element("officename").Value,
                                      ID = contact.Element("ID").Value
                                  };
```

I can pull it directly from the internet and put it into the `lstContacts`, but I can't seem to even open the file to write it to the file(that way it's available offline). [Here is my actual error put to a pastebin](http://pastebin.com/JHQnQehQ). This happens directly at `IsolatedStorageFileStream file = isoStorage.OpenFile("Components/contacts.xml", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Read);`

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. The issue was I had the file already created on my system before running this and it didn't like that.

Answer (score 0):

When you download and save the file make sure you close the file before attempting to read it again.

You should wrap File The Readers/Writers in using blocks as this is a quick and safe way to do this (see MSDN Sample below)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664736(v=vs.71).aspx

```
using System;
using System.IO;
class Test
{
   static void Main() {
      using (TextWriter w = File.CreateText("log.txt")) {
         w.WriteLine("This is line one");
         w.WriteLine("This is line two");
      }
      using (TextReader r = File.OpenText("log.txt")) {
         string s;
         while ((s = r.ReadLine()) != null) {
            Console.WriteLine(s);
         }
      }
   }
```

}